# PHP - refresh entire page from an included file?

Tags: php

At the top of every page I have a header (header.inc.php) that has a login field that I add with

```
include 'login.php';
```

The code there is:

```
<?php 
    include 'checkPassword.php';
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        if (checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = true;
            header("Refresh:0");
            exit();
        } else {
            echo '<h1>nope</h1>';
        }
    }

?>

<div id="login"> <!-- Login field with link to registration -->
    <fieldset>
    <form method="POST" action="login.php">
    <Legend>Login</Legend>
    Username <input type="text" name="username" <?php if (isset($username)) {echo "value=$username";} ?>>
    Password <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" name="login">
    <div id="register">
        <a href="registration.html">Not a member? Click here to register!</a>
    </div>
    </form>     
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

I've seen a few different methods for using `header()` to load a certain page, but the login appears at the top of every page, therefore I'd like a way for the PHP to refer to itself. However, all the methods I've found so far refer to 'login.php', instead of the page the overall page that contains the header and login.

Comment: `header('Refresh:0; index.php');` this should be the header

Comment: @Blueblazer172 Is index.php a special name? My login will appear on registration.php, search.php etc. So I was hoping for some of self referencing variable, without me having to manually add arguments

Comment: you have to put a valid file to redirect to

Comment: @Blueblazer172 So there is no "self-refresh" option? Like a way to refer to the link in the current URL?

Comment: nope i don't think so

Comment: [`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) contains the filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root.

Comment: @axiac Thanks but I think that causes the same issue, where it loads to 'login.php' instead of the overall page e.g. 'registration.php'

Comment: Have you tried? The "currently executing script" is the top-level script launched to handle the HTTP request; it doesn't change (and it doesn't care) in the included files.

Comment: @axiac ya, it actually brings back even less. Just a blank page with the username.

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
<?php 
include 'checkPassword.php';
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    if (checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = true;
        header("Refresh:0");
        exit();
    } else {
        echo '<h1>nope</h1>';
    }
}

?>
```

It refreshes your current page, and if you need to redirect it to another page, use following:

```
header("Refresh:0; url=page2.php");
```

echo meta tag like this: URL is the one where the page should be redirected to after refresh.

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=upload.php\">";
```

Comment: `header("Refresh:0; url=page2.php");` is not correct. btw how different is your answer to my comment...

Comment: look at the first comment on this answer and you'll know it

Comment: i also try echo the containt

Comment: echo '<script type="text/javascript">
               //alert("insert");
              window.location.href="url=page2.php";
            </script>';

Comment: Hey Ravi thanks for your help but this isn't quite what I'm looking for. I've seen some Javascript implementations that work but that's a lot of extra work for me right now. I'm just going have it direct you to a 'success.html' page and then give you the option to go back